# Игнорирование значений в structured binding

Tags: c++, c++17

Можно ли как-нибудь проигнорировать второе значение пары в `structured binding`?

```
auto[first, /* ? */] = get_pair(); // Как проигнорировать?
std::tie(first, std::ignore) = get_pair(); // OK
```

Comment: Для меня является загадкой, зачем в языке понадобились structured binding, и тем более непонятно, почему бы не написать просто `auto first{get_pair().first};` в данном случае

Comment: @VTT для удобного синтаксиса, ведь не надо first объявлять. Так можно или нет игнорировать?

Comment: Нельзя. Но как минимум GCC не выдает предупреждение, если хотя бы один элемент биндинга используется, так что можно просто оставить там `second`.

Comment: @VTT, деструктурирование объектов нынче в моде. Везде добавляют подобные вещи, и tuple становится «звездой».

Comment: @ixSci Ну не знаю, всякие пары / кортежи используются давным-давно, но необходимости в таком синтаксисе как-то не возникало. Обращение к полю без указания его имени или без вызова какого-то геттера мне представляется прямо-таки вредительством. Тем более удивительно добавление таких примочек, когда в языке уже и так ~20 видов инициализации переменных, большая часть из которых не нужна.

Comment: @VTT, казалось бы, да. Tuple существую давно и всё такое прочее, тем не менее, если взять тот же C#, то там можно видеть те же нововведения, просто более приятные в использовании. Лично я тоже не вижу особого применения этому, кроме «раскладывания» пар в цикле `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Этого сделать нельзя. В [оригинальном предложении](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf), написано следующее:

> Anticipating pattern matching in the language could suggest a wildcard
>   like `_` or `*`, but since we do not yet have pattern matching it is
>   premature to pick a syntax that we know will be compatible. This is a
>   pure extension that can wait to be considered with pattern matching.

Т.е. хотелось бы игнорировать с помощью `_` или `*`, но пока функционала в языке, чтобы это реализовать,— нет. `std::ignore` выглядит ужасно, поэтому даже не рассматривался. В [далеком] будущем мы вероятно увидим игнорирование, но пока, увы.